# Javascript Battery life calculator which performs division

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to code a simple calculator using Javascript and HTML. I have very little idea about Javascript followed some tutorials to build the below code. The calculator I intend to make have two fields ( Battery current and Load current ) . I need to divide battery current by Load current multiplying the current unit and resultant value should be shown when I hit calculate or when values are changed.

```js
var current_unit = new Array();
current_unit["mA"] = 1000;
current_unit["A"] = 1;

function getbattunit() {
    var currentunit1 = 0;
    var theForm1 = document.forms[batterycalculator];
    var unit1 = theform.elements["currunit"];
    var Amps1 = current_unit[unit.value];
    return Amps1;
}

function getloadunit() {
    var currentunit2 = 0;
    var theForm2 = document.forms[batterycalculator];
    var unit2 = theform.elements["loadunit"];
    var Amps2 = current_unit[unit.value];
    return Amps2;

}

function runtime() {
    var currentunit = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms[batterycalculator];
    var temp = theform.elements["loadcurr"];
    var temp1 = the form.elemets["battcurr"];
    var time = (getbattunit() * battcurr) / (getloadunit() * loadcurr); 
     document.getElementById('timeresult').innerHTML =
        "Load can be powered for" + time;

    }
```

```html
<form action="" id="batterycalculator" onsubmit="return false">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Battery life calculator</legend>
                 <label for='loadcurr'>Load current</label>
                <input type="number" id="loadcurr" name='loadcurr' />
                 <select id="currunit" name='currunit' onchange="runtime()">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="mA">mA</option>
               </select>
                 <br/>
                <br/>
                 <label for='battcurr'>Battery maximum capacity</label>
                <input type="number" id="battcurr" name='battcurr' />
                <select id="loadunit" name='loadunit' onchange="runtime()">
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="mA">mA</option>
               </select>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <div id="timeresult"> </div>                 
                 </br>
                 <button value='Submit' onclick="runtime()" />Calculate</button>
                 <br/>
                </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>  
       </form>
```

Comment: `the form.elemets` Spelling matters in programming. You also need to get the value of the elements, not just the elements themselves.

Comment: What's the specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"my recommand way"

```js
const bcForm = document.getElementById('battery-calculator')

bcForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  let time = (Number(bcForm.loadunit.value) *bcForm.battcurr.valueAsNumber )
           / (Number(bcForm.currunit.value) *bcForm.loadcurr.valueAsNumber )

  bcForm.timeResult.value = "Load can be powered for " + time.toFixed(3)
  }
```

```css
fieldset, label, input, select, output, button { 
  display: block;
  float:   left;
  margin: .3em;
  }
label, button {
  clear: both;
  width: 15em;
  }
label {
  line-height: 2em;
  overflow:    hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }
label::after {
  content: ' . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . '
  }
button, output {
  margin: 2em 2em .4em 1em;
  }
```

```html
<form id="battery-calculator">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Battery life calculator</legend>
    <label>Load current</label>
    <input type="number" name="loadcurr" value="0" min="0" >
    <select name="currunit">
      <option value="1"    select > A </option>
      <option value="1000"        > mA </option>
    </select>
    <label>Battery maximum capacity</label>
    <input type="number" name="battcurr"  value="0" min="0" >
    <select name="loadunit">
      <option value="1"    select > A </option>
      <option value="1000"        > mA </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    <output name="timeResult"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

> It worked I have implemented this in the site however the CSS is all messed up.

try to do: (with no guarantee, as I suspected you already use a responsive framework)

```
#battery-calculator fieldset,
#battery-calculator label,
#battery-calculator input,
#battery-calculator select,
#battery-calculator output,
#battery-calculator button {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: .3em;
}
#battery-calculator label,
#battery-calculator button {
 clear: both;
 width: 15em;
}
#battery-calculator label {
 line-height: 2em;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#battery-calculator label::after {
 content: ' . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ' 
}
#battery-calculator button,
#battery-calculator output {
 margin: 2em 2em .4em 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for simplifying the code. But I am not getting the right result for input values. When load draws 1 A that is when Load current field value is 1 and Battery max capacity is 3Ah or when 2nd field is 3. The output should result time units which is 3 hours but the calculator results in 0.333 hours. As far as I can the division has been made correctly but unsure what causes this problem. Can you please help ?

Comment: @FrankDonald  changed!. the division was in reverse way

Comment: Thank you :) It worked I have implemented this in the site however the CSS is all messed up. The alignment of the form is bizarre. Am guessing the CSS of the theme is meddling with this. Can you kindly look into this -> https://www.gadgetronicx.com/battery-life-calculator/ and advice :)

Comment: @FrankDonald I added a  try solution

Comment: Hi I have tried this but no luck guess my template CSS is messing up. Can I use this code and host it elsewhere then use iframe or any other method to add it in my website. Will that work ? kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

With your way. But there was a lots of spelling mistakes.

```js
var current_unit = {
  "mA": 1000,
  "A": 1
};

function getbattunit() {
    var currentunit1 = 0;
    var theForm1 = document.forms["batterycalculator"];
    var unit1 = theForm1.elements["currunit"].value;
    var Amps1 = current_unit[unit1];
    return Amps1;
}

function getloadunit() {
    var currentunit2 = 0;
    var theForm2 = document.forms["batterycalculator"];
    var unit2 = theForm2.elements["loadunit"].value;
    var Amps2 = current_unit[unit2];
    return Amps2;

}

function runtime() {
    var currentunit = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["batterycalculator"];
    var temp = theForm.elements["loadcurr"].value;
    var temp1 = theForm.elements["battcurr"].value;
    var time = (getbattunit() * temp1) / (getloadunit() * temp);
    document.getElementById('timeresult').innerHTML = "Load can be powered for " + time;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="batterycalculator" onsubmit="return false">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Battery life calculator</legend>
                 <label for='loadcurr'>Load current</label>
                <input type="number" id="loadcurr" name='loadcurr' />
                 <select id="currunit" name='currunit'>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="mA">mA</option>
               </select>
                 <br/>
                <br/>
                 <label for='battcurr'>Battery maximum capacity</label>
                <input type="number" id="battcurr" name='battcurr' />
                <select id="loadunit" name='loadunit'>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="mA">mA</option>
               </select>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <div id="timeresult"> </div>                 
                 </br>
                 <button value='Submit' onclick="runtime()" />Calculate</button>
                 <br/>
                </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>  
       </form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for making the corrections. Really appreciate your help.